# How can I create my own TCP connection (just send TCP request and get the result)?

Tags: c++, c, tcp, port

I want to connect to some server and find if the special port is open or not, so I want to send TCP packet with SYN flag set and get the result packet from server and check the result flag to find out if the port is open, closed or filtered? now my question is how can I create this TCP connection (I just need 2 way connection not 3-way handshake) please show me how can I create this special connection and how can I check special flag and how can I create my TCP connection with my desired flag.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what platform you're on, but the term you need to search for is 'raw sockets'.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest starting with file `scan_engine.cc` from [nmap](http://nmap.org/) source code; follow the `isRawScan()` function.

My quick scan through the source seems to indicate that you need to create [`SOCK_RAW`](http://sock-raw.org/papers/sock_raw) sockets *and* install a [`pcap`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) packet capture filter to read the response packets. (Perhaps the `pcap` filter is just for convenience/speed sake, but if the nmap team decided to go this route, they probably had good reasons.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Nmap](http://nmap.org/book/man.html) to scan for open ports.

Comment: I need to implement nmap myself :D can't use it's source.